# how do i handle hiddenkeys in child settings view?

Tags: ios, inappsettingskit

I have tried setting hiddenkeys to keys found in sub views, but it doesn't seem to have any effect?

I am setting the hidden keys just as in the example, and it works for elements in the "root" settings view.

Is there anyway to hide segments initially in child views?

edit: I am extending the IASKAppSettingsViewController, and i'm setting the hidden property in the init. This is a test of course. The "logout" is in the root and gets hidden, but the rest are keys for elements in different PSChildPaneSpecifiers and do not get hidden when i go to to them.

```
- (instancetype)init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.hiddenKeys = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"testGoRoot", @"logout", @"radiogroup", @"radiogroup", nil];
}

return self;
```

}

Comment: Could you please say more about hiddenkeys?

Comment: Please edit your question, if you are talking about code examples please add them. Please make sure the question you ask is clear.

Comment: Its a simple question for a specific api, i think it was pretty clear. But sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue by debugging, so i posted an issue on GitHub. It was identified as a regression bug and swiftly addressed by Futuretap (took less than an hour from when i posted the issue until a new version was committed), so this works now, with the latest version of InAppSettingsKit.

issue:
https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit/commit/2129f9a63d9d481fed46852d734309220bc06fe0